# В чем смысл escape последовательностей? Или это не они?

Tags: c, linux

Использую библиотеку `newt`, которая в свою очередь завязана на библиотеке `slang`

Есть такая функция, в которой, как я понял, задаются `escape` последовательности (они ли?), вот ее отрывок:

```
void SLtt_set_term_vtxxx(int *vt100)
{
   Norm_Vid_Str = "\033[m";

   Scroll_R_Str = "\033[%i%d;%dr";
   Cls_Str = "\033[2J\033[H";
   Rev_Vid_Str = "\033[7m";
   Bold_Vid_Str = "\033[1m";
   Blink_Vid_Str = "\033[5m";
   UnderLine_Vid_Str = "\033[4m";
   Italic_Vid_Str = "\033[3m";
   Del_Eol_Str = "\033[K";
   Del_Bol_Str = "\033[1K";
   Rev_Scroll_Str = "\033M";
}
```

К примеру, переменная `Scroll_R_Str` используется в качестве аргумента у функции `tt_sprintf` в поле `ftm` (как я понял, - формат). Эта переменная участвует в сравнениях, инкриминируется... 
Я не понимаю, как такие операции могут проводиться с ней? Что это за последовательности?... В интернете мало понятной мне информации нашел...

Comment: Это именно escape-последовательности. \033 = 27 = код для Escape.

Comment: @VladD этот символ ничего не значит? Просто показывает терминалу, что далее идет некая управляющая последовательность?

Comment: Ну, не обязательно терминалу. Устройство вывода может быть и просто консоль. Но да, этот  символ означает, что за ним управляющая последовательность, и больше ничего.

Comment: Это костыль, сначала придумали передавать только текст, затем спохватились и вспомнили что нужно передавать и команды, запрашивать статус итп

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это так называемые ANSI Escape Codes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) служат в том числе для печати красивыми цветными буквами по цветному же фону.